# Table saw blade wobbles, don't think it's the arbor

Tags: table-saw, saw-blade

So I'm never really had great cuts with this saw but never looked into why. Recently I tried to cut some 8/4 and it didn't want to move through the blade so I cleaned the blade, waxed the table and it still burns or binds. It appears the blade is wobbling so I recorded these videos in the hopes I can get some help fixing this issue.

I looked up how to check this on youtube, hopefully I'm doing it right. Using the dial indicator I first checked with nothing on the arbor and it appears to be ok, about 0.001in during the full rotation. I put the blade back on and it jumps up to about 0.011in which seems pretty high. I don't think it's the blade as this is the second blade I tried but I'm not sure what else it could be. Is this runout bad? Is it something else?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNHCN_cZk_Y&feature=youtu.be

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1nNi0MFuak&feature=youtu.be

It's a ridgid r4512 saw.
Blade in the saw was a [10 in. x 50-Teeth Combination Saw Blade](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Diablo-10-in-x-50-Teeth-Combination-Saw-Blade-D1050X/202786854?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD25T%7C25-7_POWER%20TOOL%20ACCESSORIES%7CNA%7CLIA%7C71700000043746545%7C58700004596952413%7C92700038837660303&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxNnfBRDwARIsAJlH29DygvhhQYMNhF2JeHrZaqwazmj744HNugfRPTGJXDIctWBSeboEvLkaAs9XEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: My gut says that your first measurement isn't useful enough because it's so close to the point of rotation. Can you find a third, full kerf blade to test?

Comment: And as a ps, I didn't count teeth on the blade in the video, but it seemed to have a lot of teeth to be ripping 8/4. What was the actual blade you were having issues with? And what species was it?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - That's a standard combination blade. Probably 50 teeth. All else being equal it ought to give adequate, but not necessarily great, results. It certainly should not be burning and binding.

Comment: Have you checked that the blade is flat? Also check for any irregular wear to any spacer washers.

Comment: Added the blade, 10 in. x 50-Teeth Combination Saw Blade, maybe try a dedicated ripping blade? The wood was beach. How can I tell if the blade just needs to be replaced? It was cheap, like $35

Comment: After reading more about blades it appears I should be using a thin kerf rip blade for such cuts on my saw. I'll pick one up and try this process again. I still think the blade is wobbling but if I can cut it's not that big of an issue.

Comment: Thick beech would be tough on a good day and could possibly induce wobble on a combination blade. Look forward to hearing about how the rip blade works.

Comment: For fun I just searched for "ridgid r4512 wobble" and got lots of hits, including a suggestion that there is a "well-documented defect" related to these saws. I don't know enough to make an answer, but you might want to investigate based on this information and then present your own canonical answer.

Comment: Wow, what a difference. I got a new ripping thin kerf and it's like a different saw. It appears it's still out of alignment assuming I'm checking right but no burn marks, no binding, just smooth cutting. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible it could be the blade, try turning the blade around backwards and see if the "high" spots become the "low" spots. A little bit of movement on the arbor can make a lot of movement on the end of the blade though. The washer that goes on the outside of the blade could not be sitting flat and allowing the blade to wobble as well. I used this video to straighten up an old Craftsman table saw I bought a few years back.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXFRsmB0_Ec